# LINQ DataRowExtensions.Field<int> has to be <decimal>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have odd behaviour in some C# code that uses a LINQ query to access some data in a simple DataSet table:

```
var rowConfig = from row in dsConfig.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             where row.Field<string>("SERVICE").ToUpper().Contains(trackedServType)
                             select row;

                seqMin = Convert.ToInt32(rowConfig.FirstOrDefault().Field<decimal>("ROYAL_MAIL_SEQ_MIN"));
```

If I write `FirstOrDefault().Field<int>` I get an InvalidCastException at runtime,

For some reason it has to be `decimal`.

"SERVICE" is a `numeric` type in a T SQL database

Comment: Why do you think it is odd? The type `T` you pass to `Field<T>()` method must match the [`DataColumn.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 2):

The `Numeric` data type in sql server converts to `decimal` in .net. You can see the full conversion list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are getting that error because no implicit conversion exists between decimal and any other numeric type in C#. You can see the list of [implicit conversions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), and the list of [explicit conversions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx).

Comment: Great, that answered my question perfectly, couldn't find anything on .Field<decimal> on MSDN

Comment: @Rob glad to help. Please make sure to upvote answers and questions that you find helpful or good (and in the case of answers to your own questions, mark the correct answer as correct).